# How to create a sas7bdat from r dataframe. I used some libraries like rio,haven. It is creating sas7bdat but not opening in sasa

Tags: r, sas

```
library(haven)
df
Minutes Goals
1    1234    10
2    1253    15
3     112     1

write_sas(df,"D:\\spec.sas7bdat")
```

it is created the file but not opened in sas got below error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvdBZ.png)

Comment: What happens when you run `PROC CONTENTS` on the SAS dataset?  Can you show the SAS log, as text - not photograph.

Comment: Unfortunately, this couldn't be resolved as per a GitHub case [link](https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/issues/357) Hadley himself writes that it would need reverse engineering, and SAS seems to be litigious.

Comment: Try exporting to other formats readable by SAS - csv, xls, xlsx, sav, etc [refer](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003102096.htm)

Comment: File was not opening in sas

Comment: This is because of a bug in `haven`. Check the GutHub link in my previous comment. You will not be able to use the `write_sas()` function in this case.

Comment: Is there any alternate way

Comment: export to xlsx or csv. use `proc import` to ingest the exported file. third comment from above. read the chain!

Comment: @Tom Could you please close this question, if suitable. This is a known bug in R `haven` package.

Comment: Please post code and log of what you tried that failed.  Post the R code to create the data frame. The R code to convert it to a SAS dataset and the SAS code the read the dataset. Then others an test and see if your problem is general or specific to your installation.